# Can I show only 3 contenttypes in the dropdown "New Document" in the ribbon?

Tags: document-library, content-type

I am using sp2010. I have a library with 10 content types. These 10 content types are needed. In the ribbon there is a button "New Document". When you click on the arrow you see a dropdown menu with all the contenttypes. Is it possible to see only 3? For example the first 3? Maybe some css hacking to set the height and remove scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Library settings -> then  click "Change new button order and default content type".
From there you can select which content type to be shown on new button.

[image]

And programmatically you can do this by:

```
SPContentType oCT = spList.ContentTypes[ctName];
oCT.Hidden = true;
oCT.Update();
```

Comment: I know this option. But I would like to stil use the other content types. Like for example when I click on edit properties. I would like to see there all the contenttypes. Only in the dropdownbox in the ribon "Add new document" I would like to show only 3 contenttypes.